How to find a variance for this problem?
What I want to ask about is an example from the game "Genshin Impact".
Every three A materials can be combined into one B material.
Now there are two effects：

10% probability of double output of material B
25% probability of returning one-third of material A

I plan to calculate the variance and expectation of the two options, but I don’t know how to calculate the 25% variance.
code simulation：

10% choice of expectation:
$$\mathrm{E}[X]=\mathrm{E}[\frac{b}{3}+Y_{Extra}]=\frac{b}{ 3}+np=10\% \times\frac{2}{3}b+90\% \times\frac{1}{3}b=\dfrac{11b}{30} $$
10% choice of variance :
$$\mathrm{Var}[Y]=np(1-p)=\frac{b}{3}\times0.1\times0.9=\frac{3}{100}b\\$$
25% choice of expectation:
$$\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{b}{3}\right)=\frac{b}{3} +\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{b}{3}\right)\times 25\% \times \frac{1}{3}\\$$
or
$$
 \begin{align*} \mathrm{E}\left(\frac{b}{3}\right)  &= \frac{b}{3} + \frac{b}{3} \times 25\% \times \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{b}{3} \times \left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^n \\   &= \frac{b}{3} \times (1+{\frac{1}{12}}+{\frac{1}{12}}^2+...+{\frac{1}{12}}^n) \\   &= \frac{b}{3} \times \frac{1 \times (1-{\frac{1}{12}}^n)}{1-\frac{1}{12}} \\  \end{align*}
$$
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty}\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{b}{3}\right)=\frac{4b}{11}$$
25% choice of variance (The problem):
$$\mathrm{E}[X]=\sum_1^{k}a_k=\sum_1^{k}\frac{1}{12^k}a=\sum_1^{k}\frac{1}{12^k}\frac{b}{3}$$
$$\mathrm{E}(a_k)=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[a_k| a_{k-1}]]=\mathrm{E}[\frac{1}{12}a_{k-1}]=\frac{1}{12}\mathrm{E}[a_{k-1}]\\$$
$$\mathrm{Var}(a_k)=\mathrm{Var}[\mathrm{E}(a_k|a_{{k-1}})]+\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}(a_k|a_{k-1})]$$
$$\mathrm{Var}[\mathrm{E}(a_k|a_{{k-1}})]=\mathrm{Var}[\frac{1}{12}a_{k-1}]$$
Then I don't know how to deal with it.
Thanks for your help!

It is not clear in your question whether these outcomes are independent or exclusive. It seems from your working that they are independent, but not necessarily exclusive - that there is a test for outcome 1, and a test for outcome 2, and the results of one do not have an impact on the results of the other, so let's assume that for now.
It might be more useful here to use a Probability Generating Function approach to determine the expectation, because with a PGF, we can encode both the probability (through the coefficients of our power series and the value of the outcomes (through the powers of the power series), since we have explicit values here. We can then use some pretty basic differentiation and some very basic calculations to get the expected value and variance. In specific, for a PGF $F(z)$, $\mathbb{E}(X) = F'(1)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X) = F''(1)+F'(1)-[F'(1)]^2$, very simple to determine!
For Outcome 1, we can represent each trial with the following binomial:
$$\left (\frac{1z^2}{10}+\frac{9z^1}{10}\right )$$
Here, we represent the chance of receiving 2 B-materials with $\frac{1z^2}{10}$, and the standard chance of receiving 1 B-material as $\frac{9z^1}{10}$. Since we want to determine these figures for $n$ trials, we'd just multiply this binomial by itself $n$ times, ie we take it to the $n$-th power:
$$F(z)=\left (\frac{1z^2}{10}+\frac{9z^1}{10}\right )^n$$
We can then determine the expectation by calculating $F'(1)$:
$$\begin{align*}F'(z)&=n \left(\frac{2z}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\right) \left(\frac{z^{2}}{10} + \frac{9z}{10}\right)^{n - 1}\\
F'(1)&= n \left(\frac{2}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\right) \left(\frac{1}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\right)^{n - 1}\\
&=n \left(\frac{11}{10}\right) \left(\frac{10}{10}\right)^{n - 1}\\
&=\frac{11n}{10}
\end{align*}$$
This works because differentiating powers simply multiplies the coefficient with the exponent, and because for a PGF, $F(1)=1$, the chain rule simply moves the outer exponent to the front as a coefficient (as the original function which normally stays disappears when $z=1$).
For the Variance, it's a bit more complicated - In this case, the variance is $F''(1)+F'(1)-[F'(1)]^2$, but we already have $F'(1)$, so we really just need to find $F''(1)$:
\begin{align*}
F''(z)&= \frac{n \left(\frac{z^{2}}{10} + \frac{9z}{10}\right)^{n - 1}}{5} + \left(n - 1\right) n \left(\frac{z}{5} + \frac{9}{10}\right)^{2} \left(\frac{z^{2}}{10} + \frac{9z}{10}\right)^{n - 2}\\
F''(1)&=\frac{2n}{10} + \left(n - 1\right) n \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^{2} \\
&=\frac{20n+121n^2-121n}{100}\\
&=\frac{121n^2-101n}{100}\\
\end{align*}
That should be everything we need to determine the variance:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{V}(X) &= F''(1)+F'(1)-[F'(1)]^2\\
F''(1)+F'(1)-[F'(1)]^2 &=\frac{121n^2-101n}{100}+\frac{11n}{10}-\frac{121n^2}{100}\\
&=\frac{121n^2-101n+110n-121n^2}{100}\\
&=\frac{9n}{100}
\end{align*}
So, using this approach, we seem to have $\mathbb{E}(X)=1.1$ B-materials per trial, with $\mathbb{V}(X)=0.09$ B-materials per trial.
For our A-materials, we construct our generating function as:
$$\left( \frac{1z^1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
Here, the probability for a one-third refund is represented by $\frac{1z^1}{4}$ (because one third of three is 1, and we have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance), and our failure case is $\frac{3}{4}$ (we do not get any Material A back, so we have $z^0$, or $1$). For $n$ trials:
$$F(z)=\left( \frac{1z^1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$
Let's get our expectation by differentiating once and setting $z=1$:
\begin{align*}
F'(z)&= \frac{n}{4}\left(\frac{z}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^{n - 1}\\
F'(1)&= \frac{n}{4}
\end{align*}
Differentiate $F'(z)$ again to set us up for the variance:
\begin{align*}
F''(z)&= \frac{\left(n - 1\right) n \left(\frac{z}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^{n - 2}}{16}\\
F''(1)&=\frac{n^2-n}{16}
\end{align*}
And finally calculate the variance:
\begin{align*}
F''(1)+F'(1)-[F'(1)]^2 &=\frac{n^2-n}{16}+\frac{n}{4}-\frac{n^2}{16}\\
&=\frac{n^2-n+4n-n^2}{16}\\
&=\frac{3n}{16}
\end{align*}
So, for Material A, $\mathbb{E}(X)=0.25$ A-materials per trial, with $\mathbb{V}(X)=0.1875$ A-materials per trial.
